# TSQL Select all columns without first n from function/procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, unpivot

I know this may sounds silly but I would like to create function that will process data from tables with different size.

Lets say I have first table like so:

```
ID    IRR     M0    M1
----------------------
 1      0    -10     5
 2      0    -20    10
 3      0   -100   100
 4      0    -10     0
```

And second table like so:

```
ID    IRR     M0    M1    M2
----------------------------
 1      0    -10     5    60
 2      0    -20    10     0
 3      0   -100   100   400
 4      0    -10     0    10
```

I would like to create function that will be able to process data from both tables.

I know that first column contains ID, second IRR, rest of columns will hold cash flow for specific month.

Function should be able to process all columns instead of first 2 and store result in second column.

I know that I can get all columns from specific table with:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'First_Table'
```

Problems begin when I would like to create function that will return those columns as rows.

I can create function like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UnpivotRow (@TableName  varchar(50), @FromWhichColumn int, @Row int)
RETURNS @values TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY(0, 1),
    value DECIMAL(30, 10)
)
...
```

But how this function should look?

I think that ideal for this kind of processing table should look like so:

```
ProjectID    TimePeriod    Value
--------------------------------
        1             0      -10
        1             1        5
        2             0      -20
        2             1       10
        3             0     -100
        3             1      100
        4             0      -10
        4             1        0
```

**I need to unpivot whole table without knowing number of columns.**

---

**EDIT:**
If this can't be done inside function, then maybe inside a procedure?

Comment: A generic solution requires dynamic SQL which is not allowed in a function.  If the number of tables is limited you can hardcode each case.

Comment: Then maybe a procedure? I don't want to limit this to 2 or 3 tables, I would like to have universal solution.

Comment: how do you determine the `timeperiod` field?

Comment: @bluefeet - timeperiod=0 for M0, 1 for M1... n for M(n). My tables will have cols always starting from M0 and then increasing by 1, but there can be 30,50 or more columns. All depends from needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using dynamic SQL to perform the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colTP as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('table1') and
               C.name like 'M%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')


set @query = 'SELECT id, 
              replace(timeperiod, ''M'', '''') timeperiod, 
              value
              from table1
            unpivot 
            (
               value
               for timeperiod in (' + @cols + ')
            ) u '

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b1d3/10).

This solution would have to be placed in a stored procedure.

Comment: Super fast answer :) What I need is to just pass table name as parameter. Thanks!!!